# Word problem for quadratic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Two water taps , One big , one small , are used to fill a rank of capacity 4 $m^3$ with water . Small water tap supplies water to the tank at a rate of p $m^3$ per min and the big water tap supplies the water at a rate of Q $m^3$ per min . If both taps are used at the same time , it will take $13/3$ mins to fill up the tank .

Given that filling up the tank using only the small water tap takes 5 mins longer than using only the big water tap. Form an equation in terms of Q and show that it reduces to $65q^2 + 44q - 48 = 0$

I found that $P = 12/13 - q$
After that I'm stuck and can't continue as i get confuse . Can I get help thanks !

Comment: Please make some effort. You have both $q$ and $Q$ in your question. Presumably they are the same. Similarly $p$ and $P$.

Answer (score 1):

Well from the condition we have that $4 = Q\cdot t  = p \cdot (t+5)$, where $t$ is the time required to fill the tank. Now we have that: $Q \cdot \frac {13}{3} + p \cdot \frac{13}{3} = 4 \implies Q = \frac{12}{13} - p$. Substituting we have: $Q = \frac{12}{13} - \frac{Q \cdot t}{t+5} \implies 13Qt + 65Q = 12t + 60 - 13Qt \implies 26Qt + 65Q - 12t -60 = 0$

But now also we have that: $Qt = 4$, so: $$26Qt + 65Q - 12t -60 = 0 \implies 104 + 65Q - \frac{48}{Q} - 60 = 0 \implies 65Q^2 + 44Q - 48  = 0$$

Solving this equation we obtain two roots, one negative and one positive. As it doesn't make sense we can discard the negative root and determine the value of $Q$ and conclude that $Q \approx 0.5851$. Plugging back we get that $p \approx 0.3379$

Comment: @almagest I don't know how you obtain it, but WA shows that the positive value is $q \approx 0.5851$. Also the OP didn't ask about the value, he asked about how to obtain the relation.

Comment: @almagest And yes that's the actual answer, as it forces $p \approx 0.3379$ and they both satisfy the two relations.

Comment: @almagest OK. I added that in the last paragraph of my answer, although I still insist that the OP was asking about how to derive the relation and not for the value of the variables.

Comment: Ok, as promised!

Comment: The reason I wanted more is that anyone who asks these kind of questions usually needs a fairly complete solution. To tidy up, I have deleted my earlier comments.

Comment: @almagest Well you're right to some extent. But as you might already know MSE isn't a homework solving site and it's policy is to give OPs hints and not full solutions.

Comment: I still find MSE's policy confusing and confused. Many closure votes I find bizarre. The problem is that a collection of academics were gifted an amazingly high quality site (from a software viewpoint) by a collection of coders as a spin-off from a money-making idea in the recruitment area, and the academics cannot really make up their minds (or maybe cannot agree on) what they would like the site to become :)

Comment: @almagest I tend to agree that MSE shouldn't become a homework solving site. I mean it exist there to help people, but not so that people can misuse it. I mean it exists mostly to teach people by communicating with other people, not for those people to become "slaves" and solve somebody's homework for some reputation points. At least that's my point of view when it comes to some homework questions.